# How to fix space grey Laravel Blade selection?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I am using the [PhpStorm Spacegrey Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12122-spacegray-theme) in my editor. The PHP files look great, but the Laravel `blade.php` files have an very ugly highlighting:

[image]

How can I disable it?

I also use the plugins:`Material Theme UI`, `Laravel` (Both under Downloads), `Blade` (Template Languages)

Comment: Well .. looks like that Color Scheme does not support Blade files. You need to go into `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Blade` and adjust colors as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that Color Scheme does not support Blade files. You need to go into `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Blade` and adjust colors as needed.

Most likely this would be background color for the `Directive` style (either remove it or set custom one).

[image]